# Android FirebaseStorage - How to complete download task within a time interval

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've a task that have to download an small xml file (less than 1MB) from the Firebase storage.
So I setup this code in my Activity `onCreate()` method

```
final long MAX_DOWNLOAD_BYTES=1024*1024; // 1 MB
final String FILE_PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD="items/file";

//get the storege reference
StorageReference storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

//submit the download task
Task<byte[]> downloadTask=storageReference.
        child(FILE_PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD).getBytes(MAX_DOWNLOAD_BYTES);

//adding listeners to the task
downloadTask
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            Log.d("DOWNLOAD_TASK", "SUCCESS");
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("DOWNLOAD_TASK", "FAIL");
        }
    });
```

Now, what I want is that the download will be completed within 10 seconds or cancel it and notify a failure.

I tried to add these lines before submit the task.

```
final long MAX_DOWNLOAD_TIME=10000; //10 seconds
storageReference.getStorage().setMaxDownloadRetryMillis(MAX_DOWNLOAD_TIME);
storageReference.getStorage().setMaxUploadRetryMillis(MAX_DOWNLOAD_TIME);
storageReference.getStorage().setMaxOperationRetryMillis(MAX_DOWNLOAD_TIME);
```

It works, but in some situations seems not.

For example, if my phone network fall down before the task is complete, the app "stucks", it is still responding but I can't see neither `SUCCESS` nor `FAIL` log.

I tried to add an `OnCompleteListener` in this way

```
downloadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<byte[]>() {
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<byte[]> task) {
        Log.d("DOWNLOAD_TASK", "COMPLETE");
    }
});
```

But I can't see even the `COMPLETE` log.

So, what do I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Use a Handler or some other scheduling mechanism to schedule some work to check and cancel your download.  The Firebase SDK won't provide any way to do this, so you'll have to bring your own solution.

Comment: I thought about it. This is my solution: `timeoutHandler.postDelayed(timeoutCallback, 10000)`. `timeoutCallback` is a `Runnable` in which define the timeout behaviour.

Comment: I have also defined an instance variabile of the activity `boolean isTaskActive=true`. This variable is set to `false` or by the listeners of `downloadTask` or by `timeoutCallback` of the `Handler`. I also turned the listeners into activity scoped listeners. Finally in the `onStop()` method of the activity I call `timeoutHandler.removeCallbacks(timeoutCallback)` in order to handle the callback only if this activity is the current activity. Let me know if it is a right way or can I incur into `isTaskVariabile` value issues due to the activity lifecycle?

Comment: Sounds generally OK to me.